# Windows 10 IoT Raspberry 3

Tags: c#, sqlite, path, iot, raspberry-pi3

I'm doing a c# application and i need to connect to sqlite database...

I'm using SQLite.Net - PCL and i want that the database is located in application folder and when i give the path and i run the application i have in response this error:

[image]

My database is this folder:

[image]

and i've just included that folder in the project

May you help me?

Comment: Make sure the path of your database is correct where your sqllite db file present. It looks like application is trying to look in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved! When raspberry Pi3 execute project create database file in its file system...

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the wrong database path.

An alternative way is to try the following code,

```
var path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this path where can i find the db.sqlite file? Because i want open that file with another application...

Comment: When i open the db.sqlite file in bin\ARM\Debug with another application that i use for watch database table and i didn't see the modify that i apported from code... For example i create table from code (I'm sure that the code is right) but there isn't any table in bin\ARM\Debug\Data\db.sqlite and visual studio don't show any error...